# Cloning of lead records

Tags: clone

Is there any way to find the parent of the cloned record? I have a lead record which should be cloned and i should be able to identify the lead record from the cloned new lead.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this will be you create one more field parentId on the lead object .This will be self lookup to lead itself.

You can create a simple vf to provide clone so that you can populate parent field .

If you are implementing for SI project then you may work with flows.With flows you will avoid some code